# Looking for a way to have a text go past the boundaries of the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, google-chrome, text, widget

Okay so the thing is, in my current code, I'm trying to make a text go passed the boundaries of the screen's width. Anytime i try it though, it shows me a renderflex overflow error. is there any widget in the entirety of flutter that can make it possible to have a text go passed the boundaries of the screen without displaying error. I'd really like to know

Comment: See ClipRect().

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `Scrollable` with a horizontal scroll axis and a child Widget that is wider than the parent.